# How to make a bar chart with multiple series and count

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image: 1]

I want to have `x-axis = 'brand'`, `y-axis = 'count'`, and 2 series for `'online_order'` (`True` & `False`)

How can I do this on Python (using Jupyter?)

Right now, my Y axis comes on a scale of 0-1. I want to ensure that the Y axis is automated based on the values

This is the result I am getting :

[image: Unexpected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I'm guessing the plot was made with something like the following:

  - Since the plot code is not included, it's just a guess.

```py
df.groupby(['brand', 'online_order'])['count'].size().unstack().plot.bar(legend=True)
```

[image]

- The issue is, `size` is not the value in `'count'`, it's [`.Groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) which computes group sizes, of which there is 1 of each.

### Using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/)

- The easiest way to get the desired plot is using `seaborn`, which is a high-level API for `matplolib`.

  - Use [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) with `hue='online_order'`.
  - The dataframe does not need to be reshaped.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'brand': ['Solex', 'Solex', 'Giant Bicycles', 'Giant Bicycles'], 'online_order': [False, True, True, False], 'count': [2122, 2047, 1640, 1604]})

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))
sns.barplot(x='brand', y='count', hue='online_order', data=df)
```

[image]

### Using [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

- `.pivot` changes the shape of the dataframe to accommodate the plot API

  - [image]
- This option also uses [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)

```
df.pivot('brand', 'online_order', 'count').plot.bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the data is a csv file, you can import matplotlib and pandas to create a graph and view the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv("file name here")
plt.bar(data.brand,data.count)
plt.xlabel("brand")
plt.ylabel("count")
```

Comment: It is not a csv file - it is a dataframe i created in jupyter. there should be 2 series for each brand (True & False)